# File disappear - how do i get it back?

Tags: xcode

I am really nervous  , A file on Xcode 9 is somehow turned to be red, and I have a error message saying :

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/me/Desktop/PROJECT/code/vin/vins/EditorView.swift'

 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

As you know if a file is deleted Xcode will not put it on the trash bin, **so how would I get it back , assuming I didn't closed Xcode ?**

I may deleted it accidentally, **although i don't remember doing so** and do not have a backup, and its a huge file.

Comment: its a question about xcode, not about swift, so as the tag name imply its about the software called xcode not about coding. What program for instance?

Answer (score 2):

- Select the (red) file in the Project Navigator
- Press <kbd>⌥⌘1</kbd>
- In the `Identity and Type Inspector` click on the small folder icon below the `Location` popup menu and reassign the file.

Comment: thanks, this will open a window asking me to choose a location, but i dont see my file in this window

Comment: I just found out the file is inside the folder of the project..not sure why its red

Comment: Of course this works only if the file is still available in the file system.

Comment: it is in the system. its inside the project folder. so should i just delete the red one and drag it back ?

Comment: Don't delete the red one in the project navigator. Move the file in Finder into the desired folder or navigate in the `choose location` window to the subfolder and choose the file.

Comment: omg. now i did it, and i get another error, that info.plist is not available. What is going on with xcode ?

Comment: Xcode is fine. Most likely **you** did something. ;-)

Comment: I just changed names for the groups(folders) to make some order. What it has to do with plist at all ??

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that I changed the main folder name that contains the plist and some other files. The system couldn't find the new path.
I changed it back to the previous name and it worked.

Comment: As I assumed: *Most likely **you** did something*